# Intersection of weak topologies

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a real vector space, let $X^\star$ be its algebraic dual, and fix two vector subspaces $\mathscr{A}, \mathscr{B}\subseteq X^\star$ such that $\mathscr{C}:=\mathscr{A}\cap \mathscr{B} \neq \{0\}$.

> **Question.** Is it true that a convex subset $S\subseteq X$ is closed in the both the weak topologies generated by $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ (that is, $S$ is closed in  $(X,\sigma(X,\mathscr{A})$ and $(X,\sigma(X,\mathscr{B}))$) if and only if $S$ is closed in $(X,\sigma(X,\mathscr{C}))$?

The "if" part should be trivial by the fact that $\mathscr{C}\subseteq \mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{C}\subseteq \mathscr{B}$, so that $\sigma(X,\mathscr{C})\subseteq \sigma(X,\mathscr{A})$ and $\sigma(X,\mathscr{C})\subseteq \sigma(X,\mathscr{B})$ (without the hypothesis that $S$ is convex). What about the converse?

Ps. Here, the weak topology $\sigma(X,\mathscr{A})$ is the coarser topology on $X$ such that each function in $\mathscr{A}$ is continuous.

Comment: You need to remove trivial counter-examples by considering vector subspaces instead of families. Weak topologies generated by family and by linear span of the family are the same.

Comment: Otherwise note that closed convex sets are the same for all topologies compatible with given duality in other words you need to prove that continuous linear functionals are the same for both topologies on $X.$ Continuity of linear functional on space with weak topology means that linear functional is from dual space (checked directly by continuity at 0) or by referring to Mackey-Arens theorem.

Comment: @dsh I replaced "families" with "vector subspaces", and I agree with your second comment. By Mackey's theorem, closed convex sets are the same for all compatible topologies. But, still, I am not able to provide a concrete counterexample

Comment: Is it obvious that $\sigma(X,\mathcal A)\cap \sigma(X,\mathcal B)$ is a vector space topology (or locally convex)?

Comment: @Jochen Agree. The intersection of topologies (final topology on $E$ for diagrams of morphisms $X_{\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}}\to X$ where $X_{\mathcal{A}} = (X, \sigma(X, \mathcal{A})$ and $X_{\mathcal{B}} = (X, \sigma(X, \mathcal{B})$) depends on the category. In general, final topologies in category of topological spaces $(X, (\sigma(X, \mathcal{A})\cap \sigma(X, \mathcal{B}))_{ts})$ (finer topology) and category of locally convex topological vector spaces $(X, (\sigma(X, \mathcal{A})\cap \sigma(X, \mathcal{B}))_{lctvs})$ (coarser topology) may be different.

Comment: (cont.) At this point, it looks like, it is proved that convex $X$ is closed in $(X, \sigma(X, \mathcal{C}))$ if and only if it is closed in $(X, (\sigma(X, \mathcal{A})\cap \sigma(X, \mathcal{B}))_{lctvs}).$

Comment: @dsh Your abstract considerations are fine -- but they do not answer the question as stated. I do not even see an example of two locally convex topologies on a vector space whose intersection (final topology in the category of all topological soaces) is not a locally convex vector space topology (although I strongly believe that such examples exist -- final topologies are monsters).

Comment: Here is an example of two locally convex topologies whose intersection is not a vector space topology (I think I have read it somewhere on MathOverflow but realized its meaning only now): Since all separable Fréchet spaces have the same Hamel dimension (the cardinality of $\mathbb R$, of course, the axiom of choice is assumed) there are two different Fréchet topologies $\sigma$ and $\tau$ on some vector space $X$. Then $\{0\}$ is closed as well in $(X,\sigma)$ as in $(X,\tau)$ because Fréchet spaces are Hausdorff and hence $\{0\}$ is $\sigma\cap\tau$-closed. If $(X,\sigma\cap\tau)$ were a ...

Comment: ... topological vector space, closedness of $\{0\}$ would imply Hausdorffness. But then the identical map $(X,\sigma)\to (X,\tau)$ as well as its inverse had closed graph (because of the continuity in the coarser Hausdorff topology) so that the closed graph theorem would imply $\sigma=\tau$. Still, this does not answer the question about the weak topologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building upon the example in the comments of two distinct Fréchet topologies $\sigma$ and $\tau$ on a vector space $X$, let us take $\mathscr A=(X,\sigma)'$ (the continuous dual, $\mathscr B=(X,\tau)'$, and $\mathscr C=\mathscr A \cap \mathscr B$. Then $S=\{0\}$ is closed in $\sigma(X,\mathscr A)$ and in $\sigma(X,\mathscr B)$ (because weak topologies of Hausdorff LCS are Hausdorff) but it is not closed in $\sigma(X,\mathscr C)$ because otherwise that latter locally convex topology would be Hausdorff and coarser than $\sigma$ and $\tau$ and this would imply that the identical map $(X,\sigma)\to(X,\tau)$ and its inverse had closed graph so that $\sigma=\tau$ by the closed graph theorem.

It might be possible that $\mathscr C=\{0\}$ in this situation. But this could be remedied by considering a product $\mathbb R\times X$. An additional assumption which **might** change the game would be that $\mathscr C$ separates points, i.e., $\sigma(X,\mathscr C)$ is Hausdorff.
I do not have a clue how to prove something in this case (and I am in fact rather sceptical that the claim then becomes true) -- but it excludes the example.

---

Two additional remarks:

The example shows that *final topologies* (i.e., very simple categorical colimits) depend very much on the category. For the *final locally convex topology*, I believe that your claim is true.

The existence of distinct Fréchet (or even Banach) topology follows from the fact that separable Fréchet spaces have Hamel dimension $c$, the cardinality of the reals. If you believe in the continuum hypothesis, this is very easy because they cannot be countably dimensional by Baire's theorem and the dimension cannot be bigger than $c$ because one can eaily construct a linear injection into $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. However, the continuum hypothesis is not needed as can be seen, e.g., in Corollary 2.2.5 in the book *Barrelled Locally Convex Spaces* of Bonet and Pérez Carreras.

Comment: Amazing, Jochen.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long comment.

Consider the case $0\in S.$ And topology $X_{\mathcal{A}+\mathcal{B}} = \sigma(X, \mathcal{A}+\mathcal{B}).$ Let $S^\circ = \{y\in \mathcal{A}+\mathcal{B}, \langle S, y\rangle \ge -1\}$ polar of $S.$ As $S$ is closed in $\sigma(X, \mathcal{A}),$  it should be $(S^\circ\cap \mathcal{A})^\circ = S.$ $((S^\circ\cap \mathcal{A})\cap \mathcal{B})^\circ$ is convex closure of union of $S$ and $\mathcal{B}^\circ$ in $X$ if $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are closed in $\sigma(\mathcal{A}+\mathcal{B}, X).$ So if $\mathcal{B}^\circ = \{0\}$ (separating) then $((S^\circ\cap \mathcal{A})\cap \mathcal{B})^\circ = S$ and $S$ is closed for $\sigma(X, \mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}).$ Similarly for $\mathcal{A}$ separating. Careful check shows that separateness is not important here ($S$ should contain $B^\circ$ and $A^\circ$ if $S$ is closed in $X_{\mathcal{A}},X_{\mathcal{B}}$), only "closedness" in sum.

**Remark**. I have in mind the following result: $\sigma(X/M^\circ, M)$  is quotient topology of $\sigma(X, \mathcal{A})$ if and only if $M$ is weak*-closed in $\mathcal{A}$ for $\sigma(\mathcal{A}, X).$ So maybe it is possible to derive necessary conditions for the equivalence to hold for all convex $S.$ Sufficient condition is "closedness".

Comment: Building counter-examples. If $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}, X)$ and $S^\circ$ has non-empty interior then $(S^\circ\cap \mathcal{A})^\circ = S$ if $S$ is closed in $\sigma(X, \mathcal{A}+\mathcal{B})$ because $\overline{S^\circ\cap \mathcal{A}} = S^\circ$ in this case. One can take $\mathcal{F}\subset X^*,$ then for the weak* topology $\sigma(\mathcal{F}, X)$ take 2 dense subsets in $\mathcal{F}$ with "small" intersection.